# Replace all HTML tags except for <strong>, </strong>, <b> and </b>

Tags: javascript, regex, strip-tags

In JavaScript I use this regex to remove all HTML tags from a text string:

```
t.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/g, '');
```

Now I need the same thing, but it should preserve the following tags (they should not be replaced):

```
<strong>
</strong>
<b>
</b>
```

Can you help me? I generally don't work with regexes, so I beg your pardon if this sounds too simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a negative lookahead assertion.

```js
var s = '<strong> </strong>\n<b> </b> <h1> <h2> <a href="foo.com">';
alert(s.replace(/<(?!\/?b>|\/?strong>)[^>]+>/g, ''));
```

`(?!\/?b>|\/?strong>)` negative lookahead at the start asserts that the match, ie `<` won't be followed by `/b>` or `b>` or `/strong>` or `strong>` strings.

[RegEx DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zQ0eJ9/1)

Comment: or `t.replace(/<\/?(?!(?:b|strong)>)[^>]+>/g, '');`

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this:

```
t.replace(/<(?!\/?(b|strong)(?=>|\s.*>))\/?.*?>/g, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem via the DOM:

```js
var s = '<ol><li>hello </li><li><b>world</b></li></ol>';

var node = document.createElement('div');
node.innerHTML = s;

function clean(node, allowed, target)
{
  for(var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i)
  {
    var child = node.childNodes[i];
    if (child.nodeType === 1) {
      clean(child, allowed, target);
      if (allowed.indexOf(child.nodeName) === -1) {
        [].forEach.call(child.childNodes, function(item) {
          target.appendChild(item);
        });
        node.removeChild(child);
        --i;
      }
    }
  }
}

clean(node, ['STRONG', 'B'], node);
console.log(node.innerHTML);
```

You can also opt for the dirtier version by an implementation of [`strip_tags()`](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/) in JavaScript.

Comment: This is ok, but I'm using JS in an environment where there is no DOM   :-)

Comment: @3000 Then, the last part of my answer should be applicable :D